# I just lost my save game in infinity blade 3

Tags: infinity-blade-3

I played until level 82 almost every skill is on.

The game often complain that I login as a "different" user. I have no idea what different user is that game talking about. I often don't have access to the net. I don't even know whether my game is saved at icloud or not.

Then I just turn on the game. I find out that I am back at introductory.

Anyway I know more about this? What can I do to fix this?

It looks like there is another player at level 82, whose name is "Me" and that must be my old save game.

If I go to leaderboards, I have "1" friend, named "Me" with my pic on it.

I wonder if my saved game is linked to my gamecenter account, icloud account, apple account or what?

Are all that the same?

Where is the save game located? How can I lost it?

I login to my iCloud and couldn't see infinity blade 3 save game on it.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you had Cloud saves enabled before you lost your save. To find out if you did, follow these instructions taken from the [Official FAQ](http://infinityblade.com/manual/3/faq/Save-Crash).

> 1. Delete the Infinity Blade III app from your device.
> 2. Reinstall the Infinity Blade III app from iTunes.
> 3. Launch the Infinity Blade III app.
> 4. Ensure Cloud saves are enabled from the Infinity Blade III options menu.
> 5. Your last Cloud save will be downloaded and used.

If these steps don't work, unfortunately you cannot retrieve you save, but if you choose to start the game again make sure you enable Cloud saves before you start.

Good luck

Comment: I already have cloud save enabled. I already did the above. Didn't work.

Comment: Then unfortunately there is no way to retrieve that save game that I am aware of.